# Emacs ruby-mode indentation behavior

Tags: ruby, emacs, indentation

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a,
                :time, # ms since epoch
                :b,
                :c
end
```

In text mode, the variables listed after 'a' would indent as written above, but in ruby mode they would instead be flush with 'attr_accessor'. How can I get ruby mode to indent like text mode in this situation? Note that I'd like to be able to select the whole file and hit c-m-\ to get the above indentation in addition to all the other ruby-mode.el indentation rules.

Comment: Note that Emacs will correcly indent 
    class Foo
      attr_accessor(:a,
                    :time, # ms since epoch
                    :b,
                    :c)
    end

Comment: "lisp" is not a correct tag for this question

Comment: adding parens works, thank you!

Comment: wow, this sucks.  Our coding style is to not have parens.  Is there any other way?  I'm not sure exactly what ruby-deep-indent-paren-style really means -- but it's value of "space" would imply that this should work, right?

Answer (score 12):

This hack should work in the majority of cases.

```lisp
(defadvice ruby-indent-line (after line-up-args activate)
  (let (indent prev-indent arg-indent)
    (save-excursion
      (back-to-indentation)
      (when (zerop (car (syntax-ppss)))
        (setq indent (current-column))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t\n")
        (when (eq ?, (char-before))
          (ruby-backward-sexp)
          (back-to-indentation)
          (setq prev-indent (current-column))
          (skip-syntax-forward "w_.")
          (skip-chars-forward " ")
          (setq arg-indent (current-column)))))
    (when prev-indent
      (let ((offset (- (current-column) indent)))
        (cond ((< indent prev-indent)
               (indent-line-to prev-indent))
              ((= indent prev-indent)
               (indent-line-to arg-indent)))
        (when (> offset 0) (forward-char offset))))))
```

Example:

```rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :send_email_to_author,
               :if => :author_wants_emails?,
               :unless => Proc.new { |comment| comment.post.ignore_comments? }
end
```

Comment: You're welcome! I have been using this tweak for a few months now without any major problems.

Comment: This looks cool.  When you say "without any major problems", are you just being modest?  What are some minor problems I should be aware of?

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you have a multiline block in one of the args, and it's not wrapped in parens, and `ruby-deep-indent-paren` has default value, the block body is indented relative to the beginning of the line, not the column where the called method name ends; and it looks weird if there are any arguments after this one. But that call would look ugly anyway. If you encounter anything more serious, let me know.

Comment: I've started imporving on your code and will share soon as a gist.  I see you also contribute to js2-mode.  Thanks for your work!

Comment: Sure. I wonder, though, what feature you found missing. Is it lining up of hash arguments? It may look pretty in the tutorials, but should make it harder to keep to the 80 columns limit.

Comment: Maybe "improving" is a strong word.  ;)  But I do cover a few more corner cases, and I've completely cut out ruby-indent-line with an around advice.  https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_libs/blob/master/ruby-mode-indent-fix.el

Comment: Good call with around advice. :) I should've thought of that.

Comment: Do I just put this in my .emacs? Or do I use this to edit some other file?

Comment: The former. Also see: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html

Answer (score 4):

From Remi (in comments):
Note that Emacs will correctly indent class Foo attr_accessor(:a, :time, # ms since epoch :b, :c) end – Rémi Dec 11 '10 at 8:50

You can add parens and have it indent properly -- I'm adding this here because I'm looking for unanswered questions, and this one comes up (incorrectly, since it has been answered in the comments).

Comment: Wow, this sucks.  I don't want to have to add parenthesis to get Ruby to indent correctly in this case.  Have you found any other way to make this work out?

Answer (score 2):

When using Emacs 24.4 or newer, your example will be indented like this by default.