# Emacs & Ruby: Indenting newline after comma

Tags: ruby, emacs, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emacs ruby-mode indentation behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412739/emacs-ruby-mode-indentation-behavior)

I have method with long list of arguments. I want to move them to another line. The problem is that emacs only indents them if parentheses present, like

```
my_method(arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
  )
```

But if i don't use parentheses, i get

```
my_method arg1,
arg2,
arg3
```

I've tried same code snippet in vim and it behaves just as expected:

```
my_method arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
```

Is it possible to do the same in emacs?

EDIT: answer is here: [Emacs ruby-mode indentation behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412739/emacs-ruby-mode-indentation-behavior)

Comment: This is possibly off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might get better responses moving it to the http://superuser.com/ site, which is for power-users and system administrators.

Comment: Thank you for recommendation, but I believe it's all about programming - ruby and elisp.

Comment: @theTinMan Horrible suggestion, and I wish SO folks would stop pushing this mantra - it just splits what little Emacs community there is on the stack exchange.  Look at the traffic at each site, SU gets maybe 6 Emacs questions a week and literally has TWICE the unanswered rate as SO across all time spans.

Comment: Jouni, thank you, but as you can see, your link is already in EDIT section of the question.

Comment: could you close this question then? It's making it harder to find questions that need answering. Thanks.

Comment: @lneu: please post that as an answer and accept it so the question is closed.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm pretty sure meta stack overflow has indicated such questions are on topic here.