# Indent if previous line ends with a comma

Tags: ruby, emacs, elisp

When writing ruby code, Emacs doesn't indent the line following a line ending with a comma:

```
attr_accessor :a, :b,
:c
```

I'd like to have the following line indented by one level:

```
attr_accessor :a, :b,
  :c
```

After reading `ruby-mode.el`, I don't think that this can be done easily. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If this is something that you think `ruby-mode.el` should do anyway, then whether or not you get an answer here, please consider filing an **Emacs enhancement request** for this: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412739/emacs-ruby-mode-indentation-behavior#answer-7622971) I found a way to do it:

```
(defadvice ruby-indent-line (after line-up-args activate)
  (let (indent prev-indent arg-indent)
    (save-excursion
      (back-to-indentation)
      (when (zerop (car (syntax-ppss)))
        (setq indent (current-column))
        (skip-chars-backward " \t\n")
        (when (eq ?, (char-before))
          (ruby-backward-sexp)
          (back-to-indentation)
          (setq prev-indent (current-column))
          (skip-syntax-forward "w_.")
          (skip-chars-forward " ")
          (setq arg-indent (+ (ruby-current-indentation) ruby-indent-level))))) ;; (current-column)
    (when prev-indent
      (let ((offset (- (current-column) indent)))
        (cond ((< indent prev-indent)
               (indent-line-to prev-indent))
              ((= indent prev-indent)
               (indent-line-to arg-indent)))
        (when (> offset 0) (forward-char offset))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a library to customize your needs for indentation, it's still in the works but I use it myself for Erlang-mode, maybe you'd like to check it out. I don't consider it a proper solution but it might work for you.

https://github.com/AtticHacker/indent-of-doom

It's a DSL to customize indentation, for your needs this is what you'd want to add to your emacs:

```
(setq tab-width 2) ; Set default tab with to 2
(setq doom-indent-fallback t) ; If no rules match, use default tab
(setq doom-use-tab-cycle nil) ; Don't use tab cycling
(setq my-doom '(
    ; Rules for ruby mode
    (ruby-mode . (
        ; When previous line ends on "," and starts with "attr_accessor"
        ; indent the current line as previous + 1 tab
        ((and (prev 'ends-on ",") (prev 'starts-with "attr_accessor")) (prev 'indent 1)))
    )
))
```